how to use dialog in tauri V2?
I want to open a dialog to choose a directory,
I used "cargo tauri add dialog" to add dialog plugin,
code like this:
use tauri::AppHandle;
use tauri_plugin_dialog::DialogExt;

#[tauri::command]
fn greet(name: &str, app_handle: AppHandle) -> String {
    println!("greeet");
    let file_path = app_handle.dialog().file().blocking_pick_file();
    println!("{}", file_path.unwrap());
    format!("Hello, {}! You've been greeted from Rust!", name)
}

#[cfg_attr(mobile, tauri::mobile_entry_point)]
pub fn run() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .plugin(tauri_plugin_dialog::init())
        .plugin(tauri_plugin_shell::init())
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![greet])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}

when I trigger the greet function , it stuck at the dialog open process, no errors, just crashed the program after few seconds.
how to deal with this?
and how to use "cargo create-tauri-app" command to build a tauri V1 template?
